# Deal 4 cards from a deck of 52 cards. What is the probability that we get at least one card that is diamonds?

Tags: probability

Deal 4 cards from a deck of 52 cards.

What is the probability that we get at least one card that is diamonds?

Comment: Find first the probability of no diamonds.

Answer (score 0):

If we draw four cards we must get EITHER no diamonds, or at least one diamond.

The probability of getting zero diamonds is

$$\frac{39}{52}\cdot\frac{38}{51}\cdot\frac{37}{50}\cdot\frac{36}{49}$$

since the first card can be any of $39$ non diamonds in a deck of $52$, the second can be any of remaining $38$ in the deck of $51$, etc.

Comment: So the answer is $1-\frac{39}{52}\cdot\frac{38}{51}\cdot\frac{37}{50}\cdot\frac{36}{49}\approx0.6962$

Answer (score 0):

Out of $4$ , at least one should be diamond.. that is :

$P(X\geq 1)= 1 - P(X<1)$ ,

Now , $P(X<1)=P(X=0)$ ,

You can carry on from here...